# Angular momentum, potential gravitational energy, rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, angular-momentum

Suppose a satellite of mass $m$ is orbiting a much heavier object of mass $M$ due to gravitational attraction in an elliptical orbit. The distance between the objects at which they are the closest is $r_1$ at which point the speed of $m$ is $v_1$. At the farthest point apart they are $r_2$ and $v_2$. This means that $v_1\perp r_1$ and $v_2\perp r_2$.

Given this situation, the three following equations come to my mind:

- Due to conservation of angular momentum $$mv_1r_1=mv_2r_2.$$(as
  $v_1\perp r_1$ and $v_2\perp r_2$.)
- Due to energy conservation
  $$\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2-G\frac{Mm}{r_1}=\frac{1}{2}mv_2^2-G\frac{Mm}{r_2}.$$
- Due to the fact that $v_1\perp r_1$ and $v_2\perp r_2$, the
  relationship between radius, linear velocity and centripetal
  acceleration could (?) be applied: $a=\frac{v^2}{r}$, where
  $a=\frac{GM}{r^2}$, thus: $$v_1^2r_1=GM=v_2^2r_2$$

As they give very different relationships between distances and velocities, my question is, which of them are actually applicable to the situation.

Comment: Do any of these equations directly contradict each other? It seems plausible that not all of $v_1,v_2,r_1,r_2$ are independent quantities.

Comment: The first and third equation contradict each other because, well, they are not equivalent.

Comment: Related: [Satellite in Elliptical orbit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/347978/satellite-in-elliptical-orbit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first two equations are correct, the third one is wrong.

The third equation you are trying to use the formula for centripetal acceleration $a=\frac{v^2}{r}$. However, this requires not only that the acceleration be purely radial (which it is, we're dealing with a central force) but also that the radial acceleration is zero. In general the acceleration in plane polar co-ordinates $(r,\theta)$ is:

$\vec{a} = (\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r} + (2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta})\hat{\theta}$

At the apopapse/periapse we have $\dot{r}=0$ not $\ddot{r}=0$, and $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat{r}$ as you've identified. This means the correct version of your third equation should be:

$\frac{v_1^2}{r_1}-\ddot{r}=\frac{GM}{r_1^2}$.